# ¿Modificar valor de un objeto en localstorage javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un boton que es para aumentar los likes y este llama una función que crea un objeto en el localstorage, lo que quiero es que cada vez que llame a la función me agrege ese nuevo dato a la key llamada likes que es el contador que tengo.

Esto es lo que tengo de momento, cada vez que hago refresh a la página el contador comienza nuevamente, lo que quiero es que me actualice ese valor **likes** del objeto:

```
let heroe = [];



//Contadores
let like = 0;
let dislike = 0;


function agregarLike () {  
              
    like += 1;    
    let porcentaje = like; 
  
    heroe = { nombre: 'Ironman', likes: porcentaje, dislikes: 0 };
    localStorage.setItem('superheroe', JSON.stringify(heroe));
    
}
```

Que sugerencia o guia me pueden brindar, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Yo te recomendaria que los contadores que tienes los eliminaras:

```
//Contadores
let like = 0;
let dislike = 0;
```

2.- Los likes en tu objeto `heroe` inicializalos  en **0**

```
likes:0
```

3.- Cuando des click por primera vez en el boton de like, deberas de comprobar si la variable de **localStorage** esta definida o creada, si no lo esta, la creas e inmediatamente le sumas 1 like, de lo contrario solo aumentas los likes, te muestro un ejemplo:

```
function agregarLike() {
  /*
  EN ESTA CONDICION, ESTAMOS DICIENDO: 
  "SI NO EXISTE LA VARIABLE DE localStorage superheroe"
  REALIZAREMOS LO SIGUIENTE
 */
  if (!localStorage.getItem("superheroe")) {
    //CREAMOS LA VARIABLE DE LOCALSTORAGE
    heroe = { nombre: "Ironman", likes: 0, dislikes: 0 };
    localStorage.setItem("superheroe", JSON.stringify(heroe));

    /*
      OBTENEMOS LA VARIABLE superheroe con getItem()
      RECUERDA QUE ES UN OBJETO, 
      POR LO QUE TENEMOS QUE PARSEARLA
    */

    let dataStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("superheroe"));

    //MODIFICAMOS SOLO LOS LIKES
    dataStorage.likes = dataStorage.likes + 1;

    //SOBREESCRIBIMOS LA VARIABLE de localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("superheroe", JSON.stringify(dataStorage));
  } else {
    let dataStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("superheroe"));
    dataStorage.likes = dataStorage.likes + 1;

    localStorage.setItem("superheroe", JSON.stringify(dataStorage));
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, nikola

Answer (score 0):

debes guardar el objeto que esta en localStorage en una variable, luego lo recorres buscando el Id o nombre.. lo que sea de lo que quieres editarle el numero de likes y actualizas ese valor

Comment: gracias diego monsalve.